# What could I use instead of the "using" statement in C#

Tags: c#, using

I am having trouble getting my code to work. I need to access a website that only has one line of text on it, and display it within a cmd prompt. The website is password protected so I am using webClient to store cookies and am trying to figure out how give it the username and password. The "using" statement isn't working, does anyone know what I could try instead?

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace Temperature
{
    public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        public CookieContainer m_container = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = m_container;
        }
        return request;
        }   

        using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient());
        var values = new NameValueCollection
        {
            {"username", "admin"},
            {"password","secret"},
        };
    client.UpLoadValues("http://10.10.1.52:8001/get?OID4.3.2.1=", values);

    string tempString = client.DownloadString("http://10.10.1.52:8001/get?OID4.3.2.1=");
    Stream response = myClient.OpenRead("http://10.10.1.52:8001/get?OID4.3.2.1=");
    Console.WriteLine(tempString);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this your real code?

Comment: You could try correctly using the using statement?

Comment: Always use brackets for any language construct that provides them and indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not using the `using` block correctly.  This:

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient());
```

Is basically the same as this:

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
{
}
```

You create the variable, but then don't do anything with it in the code block.  So it falls out of scope immediately.

Move your code into that code block to use the variable you created:

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        {"username", "admin"},
        {"password","secret"},
    };
    client.UpLoadValues("http://10.10.1.52:8001/get?OID4.3.2.1=", values);
    string tempString = client.DownloadString("http://10.10.1.52:8001/get?OID4.3.2.1=");
    // etc.
}
```

---

As an aside to understand what the `using` block really does, it's logically equivalent to this:

```
try
{
    var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();

    // any code you add to the block
}
finally
{
    client.Dispose();
}
```

So like any `try` block, any code which makes use of a variable declared within that block would also need to be within that block.

Comment: It's difficult to tell if this is the genuine issue since the code as posted doesn't compile (it contains other references to `client` outside of the using block)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Fair point.  It's kind of a weird question in general, and "the using statement isn't working" is hardly an effective description of the problem.  I do suspect an understanding of the `using` block is still the core of the issue at least as far as it's been presented though.  But if the OP has any further insights into the nature of the problem, that would be helpful as well.  (In fact, the code in the question won't compile for a bunch of reasons.  It's a bit of a free-hand mess...)

Comment: Yeah, sorry guys. This is the first time doing this for me. My company put me on this project and I obviously don't have any experience. I fixed my using block, but I don't think I can keep it where it is.. I have an error saying "invalid token 'using' in class, etc. I think it's because I'm putting in within a class? But moving it outside messes up all of my other variables. Sorry for not being very informed on this topic.

Comment: @KatieJ: Well, you can't put code directly inside a class like that.  It has to be in a method.  It sounds like you may want to start with some C# tutorials.  You're trying to run before you learn to walk.

Answer (score 0):

You have terminated the `using (var client ...)` with a `;` so that the `client` is not accessible anymore. So what you need to do is enclose the rest of code within the `using block`.

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        {"username", "admin"},
        {"password","secret"},
    };
    client.UpLoadValues("http://10.10.1.52:8001/get?OID4.3.2.1=", values);
    string tempString = client.DownloadString("http://10.10.1.52:8001/get?OID4.3.2.1=");
    Stream response = myClient.OpenRead("http://10.10.1.52:8001/get?OID4.3.2.1=");
    Console.WriteLine(tempString);
}
```

**Note :** I'm little bit confused about `myClient` is that a typo or any purpose full variable declared outside the `using block`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use using like that:

```
    using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
{
        var values = new NameValueCollection
        {
            {"username", "admin"},
            {"password","secret"},
        };
       client.UpLoadValues("http://10.10.1.52:8001/get?OID4.3.2.1=", values);

       string tempString = client.DownloadS`enter code here`tring("http://10.10.1.52:8001/get?OID4.3.2.1=");
        Stream response = myClient.OpenRead("http://10.10.1.52:8001/get?OID4.3.2.1=");
}
```

Because Using create a "client" when start and dispose then the using block is finished.